# How to get closure delegate to be used correctly when called within a Trait

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy trait which needs to provide  a config Closure as an argument to a library method call (it's HttpBuilder but it shouldn't matter).

For reproducing the issue, I created the following simple example:

```
trait T {
    def doIt() {
        return {
            n = 1
        }
    }
}

class Delegate {
    int n
}

class Tish implements T {
    def go() {
        def closure = doIt()
        def d = new Delegate()
        closure.delegate = d
        closure()
        assert d.n == 1
    }
}

new Tish().go()
```

This is expected to run without errors because when the closure returned by the `doIt()` method in the `T` trait is run, its delegate is set to something that can set the `n` variable to 1....

However, this does not work and I get this error:

```
 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: n for class: Tish
```

If I make `T` a class and let `Tish` extend it instead, then it works!

I tried changing the Closure's delegate strategy but that did not help.

Is this a Groovy bug or is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: Damn! This won't work with either Groovy 2.4.5 or 2.4.7.

Comment: Have you tried [reporting it as a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY)?

Comment: I am not sure this is a bug or this is how traits are supposed to work. If it is indeed a bug, I can report.

Comment: Reported as a bug as I am now convinced this should work: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found a workaround... Still, would be interesting to know if this is a bug, and if it is, when it will get fixed by the Groovy team!

**UPDATE**: [this is a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8820) and hopefully will be fixed in a Groovy release in the near future!

All calls made within the config Closure can get the actual Delegate object by calling the `getDelegate()` method, then setting all properties directly on it, like this:

```
return {
    def d = getDelegate()
    d.n = 1
}
```

Not ideal, but got me unstuck, hope it helps others...

EDIT:
As pointed about by @bdkosher in the comments, another solution is to use setter syntax in the closure:

```
return {
    setN 1
}
```

Comment: I've also discovered replacing `n = 1` with `setN(1)` allows it to work

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
def d = new Delegate()
closure.delegate = d
closure()
```

to

```
def d = new Delegate()
closure.delegate = d
closure.run()
```

this solved a pretty similar issue, that i had with Grails 3.3.8, Groovy 2.4.15, Java 1.8.0_131. No idea why but it helped.

I was trying to chase down the error and added the following outputs

```
println this
println owner
println delegate
```

and figured out that in the first case `delegate` was not changed even `closure.delegate = d` was set before executing `closure()`! If `closure.run()` is called then `delegate` was set correctly!?!

Comment: I've just tried this with Groovy 2.4.15 in the exact code I posted above, and it didn't work. Even `println delegate` throws an error from within the closure in the `doIt` method.

Comment: Groovy 2.5.2 and the latest 3.0-alpha-3 both have the same behaviour as before So I will accept my other answer with the hacky workarounds which are the only things that work.